# how to cope with text to element alignment issues

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

My designer colleague obviously aligns his text nicely justified in his Photoshop.
How can I apply his design to my code when there will always be some space around text?
I mean I can fiddle with things like negative margin, line-height (see example) or anything. But that can't be a solution.
This question most likely arose already

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/bfpPS/

html:

```
<section>
     <h1 class="wrong">WRONG</h1>
    <img src="http://creativemedias.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/a_beautiful_day___wp_pack_by_little_stock.jpg" />
     <h1 class="right">Isn't it beautiful!</h1>
</section>
```

css:

```
section, img, h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.4285714285714em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    font-family:'Lato', Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
.wrong {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    line-height: 0.7em;
}
```

Comment: I cant see a question here other than "How can I apply his design to my code when there will always be some space around text?" 
This doesn't make much sense...

Comment: "How do you get rid of the space above the heading?"

Comment: Stop trolling if you don't want to help...

Comment: My advice would be to remove all of your styling and start from scratch. That way you will develop an understanding of the cause and effect relationship between the code that you write and the appearance of the resulting page. For a start I can tell you that two <h1>'s within the same parent element don't tend to play nice with one another - most browsers style them with display:block by default. Also try a CSS reset like normalize.css and go from there.

Comment: My advice would be to educate your designer on how to design for the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We all know that "WRONG" is the right way to code this.  Your designer is wrong here, not your CSS.  Normally when I encounter situations like this, I ignore the exact design and do it how I know is the right way to do it, and then if anyone complains, I tell them that's how the web works.  Even if you set a negative margin or do something else hacky, it's going to look wrong in someone's browser who has a different font available or a larger font size set, etc.  Why bother with the hacks?  Just do it right.